# 'quantum state eraser'

Tags: quantum-information

Imagine we have a general quantum state

$$ |\Phi \rangle = a_1|1\rangle+a_2|2\rangle+ a_3|3\rangle+a_4|4\rangle+a_5|5\rangle+a_6|6\rangle. \tag{1}\label{eq:1} $$

Then could we define a linear operator action over the general state \eqref{eq:1} so
$$ T_{6}|\Phi\rangle = b_1|1\rangle+b_2|2\rangle+ b_3|3\rangle+b_4|4\rangle+b_5|5\rangle, $$
so the state $ |6\rangle $ is no longer there, it has been 'erased'.

Or if we use the iterated 'erase operator'
$$  T_{6} T_{5} T_{4} T_{3} T_{2}|\Phi \rangle = k |1\rangle $$ after repetition we will have a pure state $ |1\rangle $.

How could these 'erase' operators be defined?

Every $ T_{m} $ would be a linear operator having a matrix representation.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What does this have to do with "erasure"? And don't you have a pure state from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a simpler example where you have only three eigenstates.

Representing the state as a vector, you have:

$$|\Phi> \dot{=} \left(\matrix{a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3}\right)$$

And you want some operator $T_3$ such that:

$$
T_3 |\Phi> \dot{=} \left(\matrix{b_1 \\ b_2 \\ 0}\right)
$$

where

$$T_3 \dot{=} \mathbf{T_3} =
\left(\matrix{x_{11}\ x_{12}\ x_{13} \\ 
x_{21}\ x_{22}\ x_{23} \\
x_{31}\ x_{32}\ x_{33}}\right)
$$

i.e. you want $x_{ij}$ such that

$$
\left(\matrix{x_{11}\ x_{12}\ x_{13} \\ 
x_{21}\ x_{22}\ x_{23} \\
x_{31}\ x_{32}\ x_{33}}\right)
\left(\matrix{a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3}\right)
= \left(\matrix{b_1 \\ b_2 \\ 0}\right)
$$

One solution to that equation is

$$
\mathbf{T_3}=\left(\matrix{\frac{b_1}{a_1} 0\ 0 \\ 
0\ \frac{b_2}{a_2} 0 \\
0\ 0\ 0}\right)
$$

which gives you

$$T_3 = \frac{b_1}{a_1}|1><1| + \frac{b_2}{a_2}|2><2|$$

Other $T_i$ would be defined similarly.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i guess that if the quantum states are entangled for example $ |1,2>+b|1,3>+c|2,3> +d|1,4> $ and so on follow the same instructions

Comment: @JoseJavierGarcia, I'm afraid you are asking a question that is beyond my knowledge there, but hopefully others will weigh in with a good answer.